# Fullcalendar not showing the correct end date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, fullcalendar

fullcalendar on adding event

[image]

fullcalendar end date is one day before
[image]

As you see in the image on adding the event in full calendar the end date is adding correctly to the redux but on fetching that data and displaying it on calendar the end date is displayed one day before.

for ex: If i give the end date  14th-jan its adding correctly to the api but while displaying its showing 13th-jan one day before.

```
<FullCalendar
            {...rest}
            plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
            events={calendarEvents}
            displayEventTime={false}
            editable={hasFeatureAccess(
              permissionName,
              'updateEvent',
              groupsReferenceData
            )}
            selectable={hasFeatureAccess(
              permissionName,
              'addEvent',
              groupsReferenceData
            )}
            select={
              hasFeatureAccess(
                permissionName,
                'addEvent',
                groupsReferenceData
              )
                ? handleDateSelect
                : undefined
            }
            eventClick={
              hasFeatureAccess(
                permissionName,
                'updateEvent',
                groupsReferenceData
              )
                ? handleEventClick
                : undefined
            }
            initialView='dayGridMonth'
            height='100%'
          />
```

so on fetching the api and displaying the data on full calendar I want the correct date to be displayed.

Comment: Do you take into consideration time zones ? Your browser and server / app ?

Comment: no consideration of time zones

Comment: Read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing - it explains that in fullCalendar, end dates are treated as **exclusive**